# Distribut IOS App in App store

Tags: iphone

I have developped an IOS application for my client with my personal Individual Program. now when the app is finish my client would like to distribute the application to the app store. How can i distribut it ? thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Use Xcode to Build / Archive and submit it to the App Store. *(It's now a fairly streamlined process)*

You should read over the [`iTunes Connect Developer Guide`](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) and the [`iTunes Connect F.A.Q.'s`](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/2.0.9.7.2.29.1.7).

Comment: but my application is signed with my Individual standard program ?

Comment: Yea, thats actually a good thing that it is signed. If you want to distribute it through your clients license, then you need to create provisioning profiles and certificates using his account, and re-sign the app using those instead. THEN you can use Xcode to submit it to the App Store. You will just need to sign in using his credentials in Xcode.

Comment: @Sam - it sounds like what you really want to know is "how do I develop an app using my personal developer license, but release it in the app store using my client's account?".  If that's what you want to know, then you should edit the original question to ask that.  What you did ask is vague.